# weblogic.Deployer IllegalArgumentException when trying to deploy ear: The file list is not allowed for this operation if source is specified

Tags: java, oracle, deployment, weblogic12c, weblog

I am trying to deploy an ear-file via `weblogic.Deployer`:

```
java -cp "$WLS_JAR" weblogic.Deployer \
    -adminurl -adminurl http://localhost:7001 \
    -user weblogic \
    -password $PASSWORD\
    -deploy \
    -name myApp \
    -source /path/to/myapp.ear \
    -plan /path/to/myplan.xml \
    -verbose -debug
```

The deployer tool told me the following:

```
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -adminurl -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy -name myApp -source /path/to/myapp.ear -plan /path/to/myplan.xml -verbose -debug
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file list is not allowed for this operation if source is specified.
        at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.validateDelta(Jsr88Operation.java:218)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.validate(Jsr88Operation.java:98)
        at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:87)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
        at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
        at weblogic.Deployer.main(Deployer.java:55)
```

I followed this documentation by Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wldeployer.html#1005385
I tried to add or remove some of the CL-options, e.g. added `-stage` or/and `-upload` or the `-targets` options, but the response remained the same.
I just can't find my mistake and I can't find anything when searching for this error message...

Why is the Deployment not working and what does the tool mean by "file list", that is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized, that I had `-adminurl` twice in my command, duh! I removed one, now it works.